# In JavaScript, inject my function into a library without changing function's properties

Tags: javascript

I need to inject my own function instead of the existing one, while keeping all of the original properties. So given this code:

```js
 var lib = {
    func: function(foo) { return 1+foo; }
 };
 lib.func.bar = 10;
 lib.func.bar2 = function() { return this(this.bar); };

 // current behavior:   lib.func.bar2()  returns 11
 // needed behavior:   lib.func.bar2()  to return 12, without changing bar2()
```

I need to replace the original `func` with my own version, while keeping all of its existing functionality intact:

```js
 var newFunc = function(foo) { return foo + 2; }
 // copy the old lib.func.* to the newFunc
 $.each(lib.func, function(k,v) { newFunc[k] = v; });
 lib.func = newFunc;
```

The above seems to work, since when i call `lib.func.bar2()`, the result is 12, but this seems overly complex and potentially might cause other issues. What is the right way? Is there a way to bind the `lib.func` context to the newFunc somehow? or some other way?

Comment: Try to find another way to do what you want

Comment: the `obj` is an existing library, and i need to override its behavior. Any suggestions how I could do that?

Comment: You can't bind an execution context. A function's *this* is usually set by how it's called, so as long as the new function is called the same way as the previous, it will have the same *this*. If the old one's *this* was set using *bind*, you'll have to do that too. You can only access a function's *this* from within its execution context.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the properties to the new function, not the old one:

```
$.each(obj.func, function(k,v) { newFunc[k] = v; });
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, i meant newFunc[k]=v.  Fixed in the question, thanks.  My point is that I would rather NOT copy it, but do an "in-place-injection" somehow, keeping all existing functions intact.

Comment: @Yurik: You can't replace the code in a function, so the only option is to copy the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter what a function does when called, without creating a new different function, that would require altering the [[Code]] internal property, but most implementations don't expose it.

However, you can try this approach:

```
function code() {
  return 123; /* Whatever */
}
function f() {
  return code.apply(this, arguments); /* Redirect call to `code` */
}
f(); // 123
code = function() {
  return 'abc'; /* Whatever else */
};
f(); // 'abc
```

Comment: yes, already fixed, that was a typo.  My point is that I would rather NOT copy it, but do an "in-place-injection" somehow, keeping all existing functions intact.